# Pass external script output to Mojolicious app

Tags: jquery, perl, named-pipes, stdio, mojolicious

I have a suite of cron Perl scripts that generate spreadsheet files. I want to change these into on-demand Web forms that download the generated file. Some scripts can take more than a minute to run.

I have created a Mojolicious app that that generates a form. Using jQuery, the POST runs the script and eventually prompts the user to download the generatted spreadsheet file. This is working fine.

My problem is that I want the user to see the stdout that is generated from the script. I'm currently just using a dumb spinner while the script is running. What is the best design for doing this? I thought I would use a named pipe and a websocket, using a second thread, to receive the output and show it in the browser. I seem to be having a problem with buffering in this case. I get the output, but only after the script has completed. I'm very aware of line buffering, but I just can't seem to get Perl to do this.

Is there a better way than this? Would I be able to push the data to the browser, using the same Mojolicious process that is controlling the script?

I can supply my code, but since I'm not sure if it is even the correct design, I don't really want to steer you in the wrong direction. I'm not looking for code or fine details, but just general design help.

**EDIT:** I have been hitting my head against a wall, trying to get my script to do line buffering. No matter what an outside source says to do, it (Perl) will control the output. I will have to add this at the top of every script, if I want to force buffering:

```
select STDOUT;
$|=1;
```

Comment: Your idea of a web socket sounds correct. But it's possible that your pipe doesn't flush often, so you only get the output into your web app once it's done. As an alternative, I believe that you can send chunked responses back through a regular request with Mojo. You'd have to probably build some stuff yourself to make it send line data, and you would have to pick a content type that does not need the end of the data to deserialize, like plain text. However I'm not aware of a jQuery plugin that can deal with this kind of stream. They are mostly meant for AJAX, so they define success callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, simbabque. I am fairly certain that the delay is at the writing end of the named pipe. I just can't seem to get it to do line buffering, so it doesn't write anything until it is closed. I'm currently using Mojo::IOLoop->subprocess() and IPC::Run3/IPC::Run to execute the script, with output directed to the pipe. I am interested in your thinking of using chunked responses from Mojo. I might pursue that. I've never been very good with the click-bang disconnect between web clients and servers.

Comment: Good job about finding the buffering variable `$|`. I had assumed you already did that. Anyway, have you considered rewriting those scripts into Perl modules and using them in your Mojo app directly? If you still need them to be cronjobs, have the script just use the module, too. There are a lot of examples of how that looks in CPAN modules that bring shell utilities with them, like [my `cgi_this` script](https://metacpan.org/source/SIMBABQUE/App-CGIThis-0.003/bin/cgi_this), that turns a directory into a temporary web server.

Comment: I was trying to get by without having to modify the scripts at all. Yes, I have considered putting the script logic into modules, but wanted to wait and see if that gave me any benefit. It still seems like I would need an IPC (such as named pipe) to pass the output of the report to the web socket, unless I can them to run as one. I can see that I could get around buffering issues (by using one of the IPC::* modules), but so far I don't have enough to push me into doing that.